# what is codec_data in Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, aac, mpeg

I am new to Gstreamer and trying debug an issue with aac codec. I found different codec_data in different scenarios. Following are caps I got from the different scenarios.

> src caps: audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, level=(string)1, base-profile=(string)lc, profile=(string)lc, codec_data=(buffer)131056e59d4800, rate=(int)24000, channels=(int)2

> setcaps: audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, codec_data=(string)11900800, stream-format=(string)raw, framed=(boolean)true, enable-svp=(string)true, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2

Could you please help me to understand what is codec_data?

Answer (score 1):

`codec_data` contains additional data to initialize the decoder. E.g. it contains information about the sample rate and number of channels in the stream.

You can parse this data according to the codec being used. Check the codec specification about this data's format.